# Different versions of the same library

Tags: java, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, android-glide

I have a library which uses Glide v3

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
     provided 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2' 
}
```

And, with an `App` that uses Glide v4

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
```

If this was the case, which version of the library will the app / module use when running in the app? Will Gradle use both? Glide 3.5.2 in my library to run code and then use 4.5.0 for the app?

Comment: What's the difference between "to run code" and "for the app"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, according to Conflict Dependencies resolution it will always use the highest version, therefore Glide v4.